# Java generics error for two methods with different return types and param type

Tags: java, generics

I'm new to Java and I'm trying to do a generic method in an interface which is implemented by two classes, but I can't figure out what is the mistake that I'm doing.
So we have 2 classes Class1 and Class2 which both implement interface IMyInterface.

1. In Class1 I have a method with the following signature:

```java
public List<Type1> filter(List<Type1> list)
```

2. In Class2 I have a method with the following signature:

```java
public List<Type2> filter(List<Type2> list)
```

3. IMyInterface has method signature:

```java
<T> List<T> filter(List<T> list)
```

Result:

1. IntelliJ is saying that the class does not implement the interface when doing the above, meaning that the signature of the method in the interface is not the same as the one in the classes.
2. both methods have same erasure, yet neither overrides the other
   My goal is to use the same method with 2 different types by implementing IMyInterface instead of writing the same method twice-for each class.
   Where is my mistake and how can I fix it to achieve the above mentioned?

Comment: please share the actual code

Comment: You might need to change `IMyInterface` to `IMyInterface<T>` and just use `List<T> filter(List<T> list)`, then define the type of `T` in the classes, e.g. `Class1 implements IMyInterface<Type1>` etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<T>` in the method signature of an interface like that means both implementations must accept all types. They each only accept a single specific type.

You might be able to resolve by moving the type parameter to the interface-level.

```
interface Filterable<T> {
    List<T> filter(List<T> list);
}
```

Then your classes can specify that they're a certain kind of filterable:

```
class Class1 implements Filterable<List1> {
    public List<Type1> filter(List<Type1> list) { ... }
}
```